# Linux - Xinerama + Compositing or Twinview + Rotation?

Tags: linux, x-windows, compositing

Running Linux Mint 9 (gnome) | Geforce 460gtx

Left 1920x1080 (23" asus) | Right 2048x1052 (23" samsung)

I'd like to rotate my right hand monitor to portrait mode for coding (1052x2048) while leaving my lefthand monitor landscape.

I have discovered how to do this but I am unable to use Twinview. The problem is that Xinerama does not support compositing (to my knowledge or technical know how).

I would like to either use Twinview (with 1 monitor rotated) or Xinerama + Compositing.
Is this possible to accomplish?

Comment: Sadly it's almost two years later and I believe there still isn't a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

**man xrandr**

E.G.

xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate left

Run the command without any arguments to see available outputs. I'm not sure If I'm missing something important in your question, but in general, you can rotate your monitor in any recent distro with xrandr.